# Describing dynamically generated code with RtlAddFunctionTable on Windows x64

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, exception, 64-bit

My application (written in Delphi, but that doesn't really matter) generates chunks of code dynamically (it contains a built-in compiler). In order to let exceptions on Windows x64 work correctly, I need to describe the generated functions via `RtlAddFunctionTable`. So far so good, I've changed the code generator to only use the official prolog and epilog forms, and I've encoded them by setting up a RUNTIME_FUNCTION containing UNWIND_INFO etc.

However, a (deliberate) access violation within the generated code still leads to immediate termination of the application, so apparently something is wrong. Using `windbg`, I see the following (where `0x4c5006f` is the exception address):

```
0:000> .fnent 0x4c5006f 
Debugger function entry 00000000`05436910 for:

BeginAddress      = 00000000`00000000 
EndAddress        = 00000000`00000097
UnwindInfoAddress = 00000000`000000a0
```

However, it doesn't print the unwind info below this. I can see it from a memory window:

```
00000000`04c50000 53 56 57 55 41 54 41 55 41 56 41 57 48 83 ec 08  SVWUATAUAVAWH...
00000000`04c50010 49 89 ce 9b db e3 9b d9 3c 24 41 d9 ae e4 00 00  I.......<$A.....
00000000`04c50020 00 0f ae 5c 24 04 4c 89 f0 0f ae 90 e0 00 00 00  ...\$.L.........
00000000`04c50030 4d 8b be 28 01 00 00 4c 89 fd 49 8b 4f 08 48 85  M..(...L..I.O.H.
00000000`04c50040 c9 0f 84 1d 00 00 00 83 69 f0 01 0f 8f 13 00 00  ........i.......
00000000`04c50050 00 48 89 ca 4c 89 f1 48 83 ec 20 e8 70 41 ba fb  .H..L..H.. .pA..
00000000`04c50060 48 83 c4 20 48 33 c9 49 89 4f 08 49 8b 4f 08 48  H.. H3.I.O.I.O.H
00000000`04c50070 3b 09 ba 03 00 00 00 89 51 08 0f ae 54 24 04 9b  ;.......Q...T$..
00000000`04c50080 db e2 9b d9 2c 24 48 83 c4 08 41 5f 41 5e 41 5d  ....,$H...A_A^A]
00000000`04c50090 41 5c 5d 5f 5e 5b c3 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90  A\]_^[..........
00000000`04c500a0 01 10 09 00 10 02 0c f0 0a e0 08 d0 06 c0 04 50  ...............P
00000000`04c500b0 03 70 02 60 01 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

At offset 4c500a0, you see the unwind info (01 10 09 00), then the nine entries corresponding to the following prolog:

```
  push  rbx
  push  rsi
  push  rdi
  push  rbp
  push  r12
  push  r13
  push  r14
  push  r15
  sub   rsp, $8
```

I'm passing 0x4c50000 as the base address to `RtlAddFunctionTable`. Why is `windbg` not printing the unwind info? Am I misunderstanding how the offsets work?

Compare with a regular Delphi function:

```
0:000> .fnent 0x79caa9
Debugger function entry 00000000`05436910 for:

BeginAddress      = 00000000`0039ca70
EndAddress        = 00000000`0039caaf
UnwindInfoAddress = 00000000`005304d8

Unwind info at 00000000`009304d8, a bytes
  version 1, flags 0, prolog 8, codes 3
  frame reg 5, frame offs 0
  00: offs 8, unwind op 3, op info 0    UWOP_SET_FPREG
  01: offs 5, unwind op 2, op info 5    UWOP_ALLOC_SMALL
  02: offs 1, unwind op 0, op info 5    UWOP_PUSH_NONVOL
```

Has anyone managed to get this to work in their own code and can point me into the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://factor-language.blogspot.com/2010/04/frame-based-structured-exception.html) implementation?  In particular, the pointer to the [HotSpot Java implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jsn/hotspot/file/d9bc824aa078/src/os_cpu/windows_x86/vm/os_windows_x86.cpp) may also be of value

Comment: Yes, but they only install an exception handler and don't implement full unwinding which I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that a variety of my own bugs caused this to fail. I've discovered and fixed them and now unwinding works correctly. Specifically there were some cases where `RtlDeleteFunctionTable` was not called before `RtlAddFunctionTable` when the code was changed. Also it is important not to touch `RSP` in the function body: this makes complete sense but isn't really spelled out in the MSDN documentation.

Comment: To clarify, you can also use e.g. RBP as the frame pointer which makes it possible to change RSP if needed.